# css how to get rounded corners on button. 

Tags: jquery, html, css, rounded-corners

I have a button with CSS on it and it has no rounded corners right now. I have the left and right images (corners) how can i apply them to the CSS below? Thanks for any help.

```
.myButton
{
    background-image: url(../../Images/SubmitButtonBack.png);
    color: White;
    font-family: Verdana;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 8pt;
    width: 160px;
    height: 22px;
    border: none;
    position: relative;
    cursor: pointer;
    margin-bottom:5px;
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

CSS3 allows you to do this by specifying a `border-radius` instead

http://www.css3.info/preview/rounded-border/

Answer (score 2):

A css3 solution will work in all non-IE browsers and IE starting from version 9 (next month?).

If you want to bump up the compatibility to IE8, you can use `:before` and `:after`:

```
.myButton:before {
  content: url(/path/to/left_image);
}
.myButton:after{
  content: url(/path/to/right_image);
}
```

If IE8 is not good enough, you should use @Wolfy87's answer.

Answer (score 1):

The methods mentioned in the other answers seem to mostly involve CSS3, which is not exactly cross browser. I think you should try using the [sliding doors technique](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/slidingdoors/). It is 100% cross browser and will use the corner images you already have.

Comment: By not exactly cross browser, I mean any IE below version 9 does not support it.

Comment: I would love to know why I got a downvote for what I thought was a decent suggestion.

Comment: +1 I completely agree, good suggestion that is cross-browser compatible and doesn´t need javascript. And with a fixed-height button it´s easy to implement with no need for additional html (if the buttons are part of a list or something similar that is...).

Answer (score 1):

Use jQuery round corner plugin.

### http://jquery.malsup.com/corner/

It's supported in all browsers including IE. NO IMAGES REQUIRED. It draws corners in IE using nested divs (no images). It also has native border-radius rounding in browsers that support it (Opera 10.5+, Firefox, Safari, and Chrome). So in those browsers the plugin simply sets a css property instead.

### Here's How to use it

You need to include the jQuery and the Corner js script before `</body>`. Then write your jQuery like `<script>$('div, p').corner('10px');</script>` and place before ''. So your html will look like the below code. Here i'm making round corners for all `div` and `p` tags. If you want to do it for specific id or class then you can do something like `$('#myid').corner();`

```
<body>
    <div class="x"></div>
    <p class="y"></p>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://github.com/malsup/corner/raw/master/jquery.corner.js?v2.11"></script>
    <script>$('div, p').corner();</script>
</body>
```

### Check working example at http://jsfiddle.net/VLPpk/1

Answer (score 0):

The others have said to use `border-radius` which is 100% accurate. Here is a small demo.

http://jsfiddle.net/TJcGc/

Answer (score 0):

CSS3 gives you the ability to use rounded corners with `border-radius`, at the moments it's good to use the vendor prefixes `-webkit` and `-moz`, something like the following:

```
-moz-border-radius: 12px; /* FF1+ */
-webkit-border-radius: 12px; /* Saf3-4, iOS 1+, Android 1.5+ */
border-radius: 12px; /* Opera 10.5, IE9, Saf5, Chrome, FF4 */
```

Keep in mind that internet explorer doesn't support this property. A solution is to use a script like [css3pie](http://css3pie.com/) that brings css3 properties to internet explorer.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/sUegC/1